# How can i upload a file to server using ASIHttpRequest in objective c and receive with asp file?

Tags: ios, file-upload, asihttprequest

I need to upload a image file to my server for that i have done some coding in objective-c (mac os x application).
Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)upLoadFilesToServer:(id)sender
  {    

[networkQueue reset];

[networkQueue setDelegate:self];
[networkQueue reset];
[networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[networkQueue setUploadProgressDelegate:myProgressIndicator];
[networkQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(UploadingFailed:)];
[networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadCompleted:)];
[networkQueue setDelegate:self];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://122.166.124.229/BALMWebServiceIOS/bin/"]] autorelease];


[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value1"];
[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value2"];
[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"value3"];
[request setUploadProgressDelegate:myProgressIndicator];
[request setFile:@"/Users/administrator/Desktop/6.jpeg" forKey:@"file"];
[networkQueue addOperation:request];
[networkQueue go];

}
```

now i need to receive this file from server .while search in google most of the examples are  done with php file i dont want to do it by php file.is it possible to do by .asp file or any other files?if it possible how can i do that?

Thanks,
Hardin

Answer (score 1):

You should tag your question ASP, as there is no importance how the POST is coming to the server.

Here is an article on how to receive files with asp:
http://www.asp101.com/articles/jacob/scriptupload.asp